# Are the youngest siblings the most likely to become millionaires?

Tags: economics

[This](https://www.facebook.com/womansownmagazine/photos/a.141038532615824.33149.109004312485913/1272622532790746/?type=3) facebook meme states:

> The youngest sibling of the family is the most likely to become a millionaire"

Is this true?

Comment: may be. Based on my rigorous statistics the probability of a first child to become millionaire is 0.000000027, and the probability of the youngest child is 0.0000000283

Comment: As the youngest of three, this is great news!

Comment: @Hobbes I think they meant human families, not stuffed tiger families.  Sorry!

Comment: It's certainly not true in societies where the firstborn son inherits everything by law or custom. I'm a firstborn son, so yeah for primogeniture!